# How do I submit .jar file to the ubuntu software center

Tags: java, application-development, packaging, application-submission

I am writing an app using JAVA Swing for all platforms.
After that I want to add this app to Ubuntu Software Center for free Is it possible?

My app is just one *.jar file, its helping to play card games.

*I dont know Python language and saying the truth - dont want to learn it now.*

What should I do to be able to submit my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Before uploading to ubuntu software center
[here](http://blog.noizeramp.com/2005/08/31/packaging-java-applications-for-ubuntu-and-other-debians/) is a guide for packing .jar into deb,</strike>
It is not necessary to package your  application before submitting to ubuntu software center , you can directly upload *.jar if it is closed source app , you should provide source code if it is an open source project. Canonical will package it for you

**Links**

1. [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)
2. [How do I package my application for the Ubuntu Software Centre?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84938/how-do-i-package-my-application-for-the-ubuntu-app-store)
3. http://developer.ubuntu.com/
4. http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/

Comment: wow! first link (I mean [this link](http://blog.noizeramp.com/2005/08/31/packaging-java-applications-for-ubuntu-and-other-debians/)) is amazing!