# Publish java .jar ubuntu desktop application on ubuntu software center

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center, java, deb

I am trying to publish java desktop application written in swing to ubuntu software center.

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141939/how-do-i-submit-jar-file-to-the-ubuntu-software-center) link to packaging of .jar file into .deb file. Now to upload .deb file to ubuntu software centre I cannot find any good tutorial.

Also when I clicked on generated .deb file it got installed in ubuntu software centre as Ad On like this snapshot.

[image: installed .deb file]

Also not able to open this installed ad on .deb file , also can not find it in seach.

Any help would greatly apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The software center (or any similar GUI tool) is just a front-end. Software resides in repositories and any software added to the the Ubuntu official repositories has to be audited. There's no automated process. Alternatively you may want to consider Launchpad and host it in your own PPA.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Can we publish software hosted on launchpad/ppa to ubuntu software center.

Comment: I want users to download my software directly from ubuntu software center in one click instead using command line (adding ppa, apt-get install things)?

Comment: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/

Comment: I already created account on this . Its not accepting .deb file that I generated from .jar file

Comment: Its asking for upload snappy file

Comment: Also its saying software should be free in ppa policy. But My software would be pricable?